# how to increase timeout for jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, apache

I am using `apache httpd server` for serving my html files i.e. `localhost:8087`

My Node.js server is running in `someip:8010`.

I am sending a simple Ajax request from `localhost:8087` to `someip:8010` and waiting for response from server but:

case 1 : when response comes before 1 minute every thing is working perfectly fine .

Or...

case 2 : when response takes more than 1 minute, then in my chrome console it says

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://someip:8010/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8087' is therefore not allowed access.
```

And the Ajax error object is:

`{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}`

And after that it is not receiving any response from server.

Whereas the server is running perfectly fine and no error is shown on server side, and after 3 minutes when server is sending response my client is not receiving .

Answer (score 0):

There can be more reasons for this. The first reason is: does your you make a request to allow you to process for such a long time. Or the problem could be jquery. It is possible to change the timeout in jquery. For that you have 2 options:

- For the specific request use:

> $.ajax("http://example.com:8081",{timeout:120000})

- For all requests use:

> $.ajaxSetup({timeout:120000}

The number is the time in miliseconds.

Comment: i used this also but it is not working at all. do we need to give this somewhere in http.conf file

Comment: moreover the error is not timeout rather :{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}

Comment: Could it be that the problem is not the time of a minute, but the amount of data you are trying to send?

Comment: the data is hardly 0.5 kb, but the matter is my server is still working and sending response after 3 minutes but browser is showing error after one minute and not listening for any further response.

Comment: Does the firewall allow you to communicate to the ports from outside? Does the software the request method you are trying (post/get/put/delete)?  this looks like the request is blocked in some way.

Comment: no mark there is no blocking because if response comes under 1 minute then every thing is working fine.

Comment: Its obviously not a timeout too. And couldnt it be that it is opposite. That it takes more then 1 minute because it is blocked? on the server you will need to put up an header: 
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

on the client side it will only allow you to use json data request. trough the default http requests. (which jquery uses by defualt) you will need to use cors: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: blocked in the sense like some process is going on and after completion of that process server sends fail or success. what does Access-Control-Allow-Credentials will do?

Comment: It will allow the server to communicate with another server (domain or port number) trough async requests. By defaults the browser blocks it if the server doesnt tell the client to allow it.

Comment: Do you use cors in your javascript? Because you will have to if you communicate with another server trough async requests. If you use jquery its just about setting some parameters.